# После закрытия приложения Activity не сохраняется

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать программу, при нажатии на кнопку выскакивает сообщение и запускается таймер. Если приложение свернуть или закрыть, а потом открыть, то должно высвечиваться окно с таймером и сообщением.

Проблема в том, что при закрытии и последующем открытии приложения выскакивает первоначальное окно, где нужно нажать кнопку. Сам таймер сохраняется с использованием SharedPreferences.

Работаю в Android Studio.

Вот пример когда:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    mDBHelper = new BDGuru(this);

    try {
        mDBHelper.updateDataBase();
    } catch (IOException mIOException) {
        throw new Error("UnableToUpdateDatabase");
    }

    try {
        mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }

    //Найдем компоненты в XML разметке
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTimer);
    guruSeve = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    guruTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - guruSeve.getLong("TIME", System.currentTimeMillis());

    //Клик по кнопке
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            String product = "";
            Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Guru ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;", null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                product = cursor.getString(1);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();


            textView.setText(product);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);




            final long timer = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000 - (guruTime+guruSeve.getLong("TIME2",0));

            v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, timer);


            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = guruSeve.edit();
            editor.putLong("TIME2",guruTime+guruSeve.getLong("TIME2",0));
            editor.commit();



            new CountDownTimer(timer,1000) {



                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    mTimer.setText( "Осталось:" + " " + DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(millisUntilFinished / 1000));

                }


                public void onFinish() {

                    mTimer.setText("");

                }


            }
                    .start();
            guruTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = guruSeve.edit();
            editor2.putLong("TIME",guruTime);
            editor2.commit();



        }
    });

}
```

}

Я только учусь Java, объясните плиз! =)

Comment: Ну так у вас и  нет кода, который делает то, что у вас описано. Вам надо при старте приложения проверить, что в префах что-то есть и на это реагировать. Иначе - обычная логика.

Comment: при закрытии приложения таймер должен дальше тикать?

Comment: Таймер обратного отсчета, CountDownTimer работает правильно

Comment: Можете скинуть пример кода? или ссылку. Я новичок, а объяснить не коме =( Некоторых действий не понимаю.

Comment: Вы сохраняете время в database?

Comment: Время сохраняю в SharedPreferences, в БД хранится список сообщений, который выводиться рандомно после нажатия кнопки и запускается таймер. По окончании которого кнопка должна появиться и все сначала.